# HttpClient - "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm a trying to post the following request but I am getting a `"Unsupported Media Type"` response. I am setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
MyResult result = new MyResult();
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();               
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64ApiKey);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));               
    HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync(method, stringContent);
    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResult>(response);
    }               
}
```

Comment: What content types does the server/application allow?

Comment: @KennethK. - The site says the following `HTTP request have the Content-Type header set to application/json.`.

Comment: @mjwills - `Res.IsSuccessStatusCode` returns false, because the server returns a status code of `415` e.g. `Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: What happens if you comment out `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));`?

Comment: @mjwills - Same error message

Comment: Are you requesting your own api or is it third party site? If it is yours please add api code, if it is third party, please tell us what third party it is

Comment: @Alexander this is a 3rd part API behind a login. The 3rd party API is private

Comment: @PhillyNJ Unfortunately it's pretty hard to say since what you are doing wrong on client side since we don't know what server requires you to do.

Comment: Try posting your data as formdata specifying `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I'd suggest comparing the request you are making in C# vs Postman using something like Wireshark or Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the tips. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After inspecting the raw data sent from my code, I saw that this line was adding the charset:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

The actual data sent looked like this:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I needed to remove the charset from the request with:

```
stringContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;
```

Comment: you just saved me from a huge headache. I wonder why that charset being appended to the content type broke it?

Comment: thank you , i had spent 2 days for this issue ,

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this to not have the charset in the Content-Type:
`new StringContent(json, new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json", null));`